# Getting height attributes of an element for D3 visualisation in angular 2

Tags: angular, d3.js, primeng

I'm currently using Angular 2, primeNG and D3 to create a particular application.

For this application, I need a primeNG dataTable and a D3 visualisation to be placed side by side.

The HTML structure looks something like this, with primeNG's `ui-g` class handling the height adjustment, and the `ui-g-XX` class behaving similarly to bootstrap's grid system.

```
<div class="ui-g">
    <p-dataTable class="ui-g-4">
        Columns...
    <p-dataTable>
    <svg class="ui-g-8"> 
        Visualistion...
    </svg>
</div>
```

Up till this point, I have no problems. In my browser, I can see that p-dataTable and the svg elements are properly aligned. However, the d3 visualisation does not render properly, [as can be seen here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fvy6.png) Basically, the visualisation is being drawn with "old" height values (the default svg height of 150px) before the height is updated (The red outline shows the final svg size)

Since the primeng classes are updating the component heights after my code reads the height values, I tried to use the various Angular lifecycle hooks to see if I could find one that allows me to get the height after the css is applied, but i couldn't find one that did.

So my question is, does anyone have any idea how I can wait for angular to render the entire view before reading the height values of the components? Alternatively, If anyone has any better approaches to suggest, I will greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you setup a plunker to demonstrate the problem. I'm not following what exactly is the render issue you are seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm simply using timeout for a similar problem, I need to wait for some d3 elements to render, get attributes from them, then render more elements on top

```
setTimeout(timer, 1500);
function timer(){... more d3.
```

so this gives 1.5 seconds for the first stage to render, before the next layer, which is wrapped in the timer function.

Edit: [here's a link to some of the timeout info from jQuery...](https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-settimeout-function-examples/)

Comment: Just finished playing around with this, managed to get the time down to 150 ms... So 1500 was way ott, but it got me thinking along the right way.